# Excel user form keeps resetting control tip text

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user form in Excel and all of the text boxes have control tip text. Since I have a lot of text boxes and control tip texts that I am reusing in many Excel workbooks, I found it easier to edit the text in a settings sheet then use a macro to assign the text from the sheet to the controls on my form. This gives me the benefit of using find & replace and it's easier to edit text in a sheet compared to using the properties menu. The macro assigns the control tip text like this:

```
With formSettings
    .textBox1.ControlTipText = Sheets("Settings").Cells(4, 12).Text
End With
```

But the behavior is bizarre. When I run the macro then open the form from the interface I see the new control tip text assigned to the controls. But if I close the form and reopen it, it resets back to the previous control tip text. Any idea why this occurs? I have tried saving before opening the form as well as saving, closing the workbook, then reopening, but I can't seem to figure out why it assigns the control tip text then reverts.

I know that I can force new text at run time by assigning it in the UserForm_Initialize sub, but I'd prefer not to since that would add a layer of inefficiency.

Comment: Have you attempted to call your assigning macro during the initialization of the userform?

Comment: `But if I close the form and reopen it, it resets back to the previous control tip text. Any idea why this occurs?` That is the default behaviour. Once you close (Unload) the form, All those changes "to the form" are lost. Either assign them in the `UserForm_Initialize` or before you `.Show` the form.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=dtSdrjjVXrwC&pg=PA884&lpg=PA884&dq=userform+runtime+vs+design+time&source=bl&ots=yWi4grprVi&sig=ACfU3U1KWPMWY0z-hil9aM9wvM1LKrGThg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjin_zjgKvjAhVQrJ4KHUZFAKoQ6AEwBXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=userform%20runtime%20vs%20design%20time&f=false

Comment: @TimWilliams - that is a good answer that warrants more than just a comment

Comment: @Sam - it maybe does warrant a full write-up, but that already exists at the link I posted (and other places), so I'm Ok with just posting the link.  Sid already explained the situation well enough I thought.  Mostly posting the link for the section title "Design-time versus run-time userform manipulations" to give the OP some terms to google for...

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the concept of *instance*. A `UserForm` is a class, and classes define the shape/interface of an *object*. What's special about a `UserForm` is that 1) it has a visual designer, and 2) it has a hidden `VB_PredeclaredId` attribute set to `True`, which means the class has a *default instance*.

When you do this:

```
UserForm1.Show
```

You are invoking the `Show` method against the *default instance* of the form. When that form is closed, the object is destroyed... until it's automatically created again the next time you reference the `UserForm1` default instance.

> *I know that I can force new text at run time by assigning it in the UserForm_Initialize sub, but I'd prefer not to since that would add a layer of inefficiency.*

Not at all. Something, somewhere needs to initialize the form. If your form controls need to be configured at run-time, `UserForm_Initialize` is the **single best possible place** to initiate this configuration - it ensures that *every time* a new instance of the form is created, it's properly initialized. In the case of an instruction like `UserForm1.Show`, the handler runs at the `.` dereferencing operator, just before the `Show` method is invoked.

The object retains its state as long as it exists. Problem is, "X'ing-out" of the form will destroy the object, and thus reset it to its original, design-time state.

You can prevent the form instance from self-destructing by handling the `QueryClose` event and setting the `Cancel` parameter to `True` when the `CloseMode` parameter value is [`VbQueryClose.vbFormControlMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/microsoft_general_purpose_programming_languages/ms-vbal/89023539-ebf1-4e5c-ac50-b7d335ec42d3), and then `Hide`ing the form rather than destroying it - of course you should never `Unload` the form either.

Dealing with a `UserForm` becomes much simpler when *you* control when it's created, *and when it's destroyed*. In other words, when you **avoid using its default instance** to store any state.

```
With New UserForm1 ' _Initialize handler runs
    '..setup initial form state here..
    .Show
    '..access form state here..
End With ' _Terminate handler runs, object is destroyed
```

I wrote articles [UserForm1.Show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/) and [About Class Modules](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/07/08/about-class-modules/) covering these topics in-depth.

Comment: So do you mean to say that the form object does not exist outside of run-time?

Comment: Kind of. In the case of MSForms it's a bit more complicated than that because the designer is itself an instance of the form (and notice how the designer is automatically closed in the VBE whenever the form is running, and reopens when the running form instance is destroyed), but yes, an *object* can only ever exist at run-time. If there's no runtime/execution context, there can be no objects; a class is a *data type*, an *instance* of a class is an object.